# Fade in whole Application with QML

Tags: qt, qml

How can I fade in the whole application? I tried using `OpacityAnimator` in the following code:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    OpacityAnimator
    {
        id: animator
        target: mainWindow;
        from: 0;
        to: 1;
        duration: 10000
        running: false
    }

    Rectangle
    {
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 200
        height: 200
        color: "black"
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. The error message is:

> ```
> W libFinal.so: qrc:/main.qml:15:9: Unable to assign QQuickWindowQmlImpl to QQuickItem
> ```

Comment: I use this App on Android and I found out, the opacity in `Window` is generally not working. Should I update my question to this?

Comment: The general problem was, the `Window` can't be set a opacity in Android, but the marked Solution works on Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`NumberAnimation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-numberanimation.html) instead:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    opacity: 0

    NumberAnimation on opacity {
        from: 0
        to: 1
        duration: 1000
        running: true
    }

    Rectangle {
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 200
        height: 200
        color: "black"
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `NumberAnimation on opacity { ... }` for syntactic sugar. :)

Comment: Yes, indeed! I updated my answer with your enhancement :-)

Answer (score 4):

[OpacityAnimator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-opacityanimator.html) as the error points as a [target](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animator.html#target-prop) to a QQuickItem but Window is not. What you must pass the [contentItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#contentItem-prop):

```
OpacityAnimator
{
    id: animator
    target: mainWindow.contentItem // <---
    from: 0
    to: 1
    duration: 10000
    running: true
}
```